# Pandas - map dictionary keys and values to new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df:

```
Int64Index: 3572 entries
Data columns (total 58 columns):
```

with a column 'team':

```
 #   Column                        Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------                        --------------  -----  
...
 13  team                         3572 non-null   object 
...
```

which has items below as unique values, repeated multiple times:

```
teams = [
    'Grêmio','Internacional', 'Palmeiras', 'Ceará', 
    'Bragantino', 'Corinthians', 'Botafogo', 'Fluminense', 
    'Flamengo', 'Athlético-PR','Coritiba': 'São Paulo',
    'Bahia', 'Sport', 'Fortaleza', 'Atlético-GO',
    'Goiás', 'Santos', 'Atlético-MG', 'Vasco']
```

---

Now, based on the dictionary below:

```
next_round = {
    'Grêmio':'Internacional', 'Palmeiras': 'Ceará', 
    'Bragantino': 'Corinthians', 'Botafogo': 'Fluminense', 
    'Flamengo': 'Athlético-PR','Coritiba': 'São Paulo',
    'Bahia': 'Sport', 'Fortaleza': 'Atlético-GO',
    'Goiás': 'Santos', 'Atlético-MG': 'Vasco'}
```

---

I would like to:

1. create a new column `df['home_dummy']`
2. assign the value 'home' to `df['home_dummy']` if `df['team']` row value is the dictionary `key`
3. assign the value 'away' to `df['home_dummy']` if `df['team]` row value is the dictionary `value`

as in `key, value in next_round.items()`

Example:

```
team            home_dummy /
...
Grêmio          home
Internacional   away
Palmeiras       home
Vasco           away
Coritiba        home
...
```

---

What is `pandas` way of doing this?

Comment: can you please give an example of the output so we know what you are looking for please. I dont understand what key would be. Where will the lookup come from to check against key or value.  In other words, can you please provide sample source data and sample desired output. one for home and one for away please.

Comment: @JoeFerndz key is the dictionay key, as in `k, v in next_round.items()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['Grêmio'],['Internacional'],['Palmeiras'],['Vasco'],['Coritiba']],columns = ['teams'])
next_round = {
    'Grêmio':'Internacional', 'Palmeiras': 'Ceará', 
    'Bragantino': 'Corinthians', 'Botafogo': 'Fluminense', 
    'Flamengo': 'Athlético-PR','Coritiba': 'São Paulo',
    'Bahia': 'Sport', 'Fortaleza': 'Atlético-GO',
    'Goiás': 'Santos', 'Atlético-MG': 'Vasco'}
df['home_dummy'] = ['home' if x in next_round.keys() else 'away' for x in df['teams'] ]
df

   teams    home_dummy
0   Grêmio  home
1   Internacional   away
2   Palmeiras   home
3   Vasco   away
4   Coritiba    home
```